# カス in the context of 俺はやる lyrics by Wanyudo

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

I can't figure out the meaning of the chorus from the song [俺はやる](https://open.spotify.com/album/6fOCGZWnxLM470jA03azno) by Wanyudo. Particularly I have a problem with the word カス.

The context is as follows (someone transcribed the full lyrics [here](https://pay-design.net/01/2019/05/27/%e8%bc%aa%e5%85%a5%e9%81%93-%e4%bf%ba%e3%81%af%e3%82%84%e3%82%8b-%e3%83%95%e3%83%aa%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%82%bf%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%83%80%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b8%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e5%85%a5/#comment-122813), the link contains also a live performance of this song without the need for Spotify account):

> 口だけのカス朽ち果てろよ
>   こんな奴が相手じゃ誰も付き合えんよな
>   期待を裏切り嘘をつき人の道に背き
>   偽善者の人見知り繁華街のごろつき
>   ...
>   俺はやる やりたいやらなくちゃそれはカス
>   俺はやる 必ず俺はやる声枯らす
>   俺はやる やりたいやらなくちゃそれはカス
>   俺はやる 必ず俺はやる声枯らす

From the first phrase (口だけのカス) I guess カス is a noun and it might be used in the fifth meaning here: [dregs (e.g. of society); scum; dross](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9) (and etymologically coming from カストリ文化) for someone who lives only from "their mouth", i.e. this rapper.

I imagine the first line (口だけのカス朽ち果てろよ) is something that he hears (from imperative form of 朽ち果てろ) and the meaning of what follows and the chorus would be an answer to it - something like "*this is how I live, this is the way of カス*."

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

口だけ(の/だ) is a phrase used to mean "all talk", as in someone who talks big, but doesn't ever do anything they say they will.

So 口だけのカス means "pieces of s**t who are all talk".

Comment: The chorus, by the way, says "Me? I __do__. Those who say 'I __wanna__' or 'I __gotta__', those people are filth. Me? I __do__. I do it 100%, make my voice go hoarse."

Comment: This makes sense, but I think the actual answer to my question is in your comment.